# How can I change or invert/reverse colors of a DOS program running on Windows?

Tags: windows, colors, console

Example program (a simple game):

[image]

Desired results (fliped colors, but manual specification of colors would be OK too):

[image]

**Reasons** to obtain this:

- I would like to run a backup copy of the DOS program that manages my enterprise (accountability... etc) that, so, contains old data. It is very important for me that every employee that uses it constantly remembers that he is **not running the up-to-date version** (to avoid new data insertion, for example). So, I thought about stron colors change. Ideas for any other method would be, by the way, thanked.

Further **data**:

- Additional **software** solutions accepted. Open source preferred. Free versions preferred, but would accept payment versions as last resource.

Comment: Give a try to https://conemu.github.io You may choose color palette for any console or application running inside ConEmu.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vDos (www.vdos.info) to run your (business) DOS programs in Windows. You can then set any of the 16 DOS colors to whatever you like (not just switch them).